# Include files on npm package but not on the git repo

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I have a fairly straightforward question it possible to include in the npm release the artifacts (files) but avoid to include them in the git repo (I guess with a combination of `.npmignore` and `.gitignore`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this is absolutely possible.

The way that npm handles this is during publish as follows:

1. Check if there is an `.npmignore` file present. If yes, exclude those files from the release. If not, fallback to step 2.
2. (*optional*) Check if there is a `.gitignore` file present. If yes, exclude those files from the release.

So, if you want to keep everything in your npm release, but avoid pushing them to your git repository, all you need to do is put those files in `.gitignore` and create an empty `.npmignore` file.

This way, npm won't try to fallback to `.gitignore`.